# How can one create an attribute with administrative tabular content entry like the Tier Price attribute has?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes

I would like to create an attribute that has tabular content much like the *Tier Price*. **Where can I find examples of how to define an *admin* frontend client-side controller like Tier Price has?** I am new to Magento so terminology of what these things are called would be helpful.

[image]

In the case of *Tier Price*, I have come to understand that the in-browser frontend tabular data entry control actually just serializes its content and stores a parsable string to a 'text' field (re: [Why is Magento's "Tier Price" attribute of the type "text"?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16851/why-is-magentos-tier-price-attribute-of-the-type-text)).

It seems like most of the heavy lifting would be done in a .phtml template. Is *any* processing done within a server-side controller or is it all HTML/JavaScript that makes such attributes work?

I am currently on Magento 1.9.x

Comment: picked a pretty hard one to start with Magento ;)

Comment: leave it to me to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Attribute is created here:

https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1264aee821b451b3c88e55659cd1ee79d3b324af/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L590

Magento uses this class for the Resource Setup because of this configuration:
https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml#L419

In the attribute array the Backend Model is defined which is responsible for the loading and the saving of the attribute, which you can find here:

https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Tierprice.php#L35

Parent:
https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Groupprice/Abstract.php#L217

From your question I assume that you have already found the template with the js in it (Not the fanciest one)?
https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1264aee821b451b3c88e55659cd1ee79d3b324af/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/price/tier.phtml

Comment: This points me in the direction I was looking for. I'm sure there are A LOT more details. Thanks much, David.

Comment: For others trying to do the same, here are some things that helped me: 1) what you are trying to create is a custom "input renderer" and 2) Marius helped A TON with this fairly detailed example here - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38434/adminhtml-how-to-add-custom-template-for-custom-product-attribute